# How can I solve "Collection was mutated while being enumerated", @synrchonized, mutableCopy, or something else?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, grand-central-dispatch, synchronized

In Crashlytics, I'm seeing a crash that my users are experiencing quite infrequently. The offending code looks like this...

```
- (void)updateIsAnsweredField:(NSArray *)moduleItemsList
{
    if (moduleItemsList && self.answeredItems && self.answeredItems.count > 0) {
        for (ModuleItem * item in moduleItemsList) { // "Collection was mutated while being enumerated"
            if ([item isKindOfClass:[ModuleItem class]] && [item shouldCheckIfAnswered]) {
                item.answered = [self isAnsweredItem:item.moduleID];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error given by Crashlytics can be seen in a comment in the code snippet above.

I assume there are a few ways to go about solving this.

1) wrap everything inside the function in @synchronized(moduleItemsList) {}. Is this the ideal way to solve? I've heard @synchronized is very slow and to avoid it when possible.

2) Create a copy a la `NSMutableArray *copyModuleItemsList = [moduleItemsList mutableCopy];`. Then enumerate that. Would this solve the issue? I would assume it would solve this particular issue, but there would be another problem no? That being... at the end when we go to assign our copy back to our original a la `moduleItemsList = copyModuleItemsList;`, moduleItemsList may have changed in the meantime on a different thread.

3) Trace the passed in `:(NSArray *)moduleItemsList` to whomever holds it as a property. Then overwrite the getter to use dispatch_sync, and the setter to use dispatch_barrier_async. However, there is no guarantee that the original array is a property of any class whose getter and setter can be overridden. And actually, none of this makes sense since we wouldn't be specifically changing that array would we?

I'm a bit confused. Can anyone assist in this matter? Is #1 the option I want?

EDIT: Adding more code

`[item shouldCheckIFAnswered]`:

This just checks a @property value that exists on the ModuleItem class. `if self.moduleType == ModuleTypeSuchAndSuch`

`isAnsweredItem:`:

```
- (BOOL)isAnsweredItem:(NSString *)moduleID
{
    if (!self.answeredItems) {
        return NO;
    }

    return [self.answeredItems containsObject:moduleID];
}
```

Comment: Item 1 will probably not fix it as the modifier of the array is outside the synchronization boundary (synchronized only works if everyone who's modifying is synchronized). You don't need a mutable copy; the copy itself just needs to be a static copy (you're not mutating it yourself) i.e. `[moduleItemsList copy]`. I don't get the reason for copying it back, though, because it's an array of objects, altering the objects should affect those in the other container as well - it's only a shallow copy of them.

Comment: Just adding `copy` will not fix problem - there is still a possibility that `moduleItemsList ` will be mutated in another thread during copying. That will also lead to crash.

Comment: @BorisVerebsky how would you solve this?

Comment: What are you doing inside your shouldCheckIfAnswered and isAnsweredItem methods? Can you provide code for those two methods also

Comment: @Arun Added to original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your post, it sounds like the `moduleItemsList` is getting modified in another thread. The "correct" way to fix this is going to depend on what the desired relationship between the state in the other thread and the state in this thread is.

If you use `@synchronized(moduleItemsList)` in *both* this code, and in the code that modifies the collection in the other thread, then when this code runs, it'll always have an "up to date" view of `moduleItemsList`.

If you copy the `moduleItemsList` into another object, then when this code runs, it might set the `answered` value on an item that's no longer in the `moduleItemsList`, or it might fail to set the `answered` flag on an item that was recently added to `moduleItemsList`.

In general, the `@synchronized` version is the easier way to get "correct" behavior. You'd only want to use copy if you're sure that it doesn't matter that the two threads may disagree about the current contents of `moduleItemsList`.

> I've heard @synchronized is very slow and to avoid it when possible.

This is *terrible* advice, in general. `@synchronized` is just as slow as it needs to be to ensure consistent state between threads, and to provide a re-entrant lock. You don't want to just throw `@synchronized` around everything, willy-nilly, but it's a fine solution to synchronizing data access between threads - that's what it's *for*, after all.

Comment: @synchronized takes a lot less than a microsecond. A crash, on the other hand, ...

Comment: Exactly right, @gnasher729. I mean, I *get* it - I work on an app with hundreds of threads, and too much locking is a performance problem that can be hard to track down (because the impact is diffused over a bunch of threads), but people are way too eager to try to be "clever" in multithreaded code, to avoid the "overhead" of locking. Unless you're writing truly high-performance code, use the simplest synchronization you can get away with.

Comment: @MarkBessey Thanks. I should clarify the "I've heard synchronized is very slow and to avoid it when possible." comment. I've heard that there are "incorrect ways to do it, correct but not performant ways (synchronized), and correct more performant and simpler ways (serial queue)."